# Как создать множественную загрузку файлов с CreateView?

Tags: python, django

В оф. документации сказано, что для загрузки нескольких файлов в 1 форму нужно использовать отдельную форму (forms.Form причем, а не ModelForm) и FormView класс для обработки. А у меня есть проект, где пользователь оставляет комментарии и у него должна быть возможность загружать несколько (сколько хочет) картинок. И создание такого комментария завязано на CreateView.

Никак с CreateView нельзя совместить код, позволяющий загрузку нескольких фото в 1 форму? Только FormView нужно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это и не самый лучший вариант, но хотя-бы рабочий.

models.py(Comment - заменить на название модели комментария):

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery')
```

views.py(Comment - заменить на название модели комментария):

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_comment = form.save()
        for item in self.request.FILES.getlist('gallery'):
            Gallery.objects.create(image=item, comment=new_comment)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

comment_form.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input name="gallery" type="file" size="50" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Вывести все изображения, которые привязаны по ключу можно будет через:

```
{% for image_obj in comment.gallery.all %}
    <img src="{{ image_obj.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Подробнее тут: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Но при таком коде <input name="gallery" type="file" size="50" accept="image/*" multiple>форма позволяет принять только 1 фотографию. Если попытаться загрузить вторую, то первая исчезает и заменяется текущей. Как быть? Надо чтобы несколько фото за раз к 1 посту пользователь мог прикрепить....

Comment: @АлександрГрайс этот инпут позволяет выбрать много файлов, просто зажимайте CTRL и кликайте на иконки файлов в вызванном окошке. Если нужно выбирать каждый файл по отдельности - смотрите тогда в сторону JS(в этом случае надо будет только изменить шаблон, класс представления остается без изменений).

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо вам большое за вашу помощь. Я просто не знал, что CTRL надо зажимать. Отметил решением.